# Read date from file using java

Tags: java, date, filereader

I'm triyng to make a program read a date from a txt file into a Date object. Here is the code I'm using :

```
reader = new FileReader(fich); 
rd = new Scanner(reader);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
Date tmpdate= formatter.parse(rd.nextLine());
```

And this is the line I want to read:
Fri Feb 20 01:23:35 GMT 2015

and then it shows up this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Feb 20 01:23:35 GMT 2015"

what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `Fri` and `Feb` are not correct names in your locale. Try specifying one where they are correct like `Locale.ENGLISH`.

So instead of

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
```

use

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i have already tried to put the Locale.ENGLISH, then it shows this error:   Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Comment: `No line found` is usually thrown from Scanner when it has no more lines to read, but you still call `nextLine()`.

Comment: ohh. Thanks mate it worked like a charm. i´m still new to java